# Problems with nested loops - How to start from 0?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, loop

I have :

- 12 lines feature classes (lineFC)
- A polygon feature class (grid)
- Another polygon feature class with much bigger polygons (gridDivision)

[image]

The process:

- Select one lines FC from a list
- Select one gridDivision
- Select all polygons in grid inside gridDivision
- Select lines inside gridDivision
- Make spatial join between lines and grid

This is done for all gridDivision. There is a loop with a SearchCursor that looks for the oid. The result is 5 spatial join FC

Once this is done all 5 spatial joins are merged and converted to a raster.

**The problem:**

This works fine for the first line feature class from the list. The second time the loop runs the oid doesn't start from 0 but it stays at the last value. So I don't get 5 spatial joins but only one.

**WHY?**

I have tried cursor.reset() but it didn't work.

I have tried with different indentations of the loops but it didn't work either.

```
# Import
import arcpy
import time
import re

# Set timer
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()

# Set environment
arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\DensityMaps\DensityMapsTest.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set local variables and make layers
gridDivision = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("GridDivisionTEST", "GridDivisionTEST_lyr")
grid = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"E:\DensityMaps\DensityMaps1Km_1.gdb\Grid1km_Clip_EraseOutsideBaltic", "Grid1km_Clip_EraseOutsideBaltic_lyr")

matchOption = "INTERSECT"

# Make list of all lines
linesList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Lines_Project")

#print linesList

# Go through all lines feature classes
for lineFC in linesList:
    print "THIS IS THE LINE FILE: "+lineFC
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(gridDivision, ["OID@"]) as cursor:
        for oid in cursor:
            print (oid[0])
            #print "THIS IS THE OID  " +str(oid[0])

            # Prepare to make the query to select one big square from GridDivision at a time
            descObj = arcpy.Describe(gridDivision)
            field = descObj.OIDFieldName
            df = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(gridDivision,field)
            query = df + " = " + str(oid[0])
            #print query

            #Select squares of gridDivision starting with 1
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(gridDivision, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
            print "GridDivision number "+str(oid[0])+" selected: "+str(datetime.now() - startTime)

            # Select grid inside gridDivision
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(grid, "WITHIN", gridDivision)
            print "Grid selected: "+str(datetime.now() - startTime)

            # Make layer of the selection. (This is to hold the selection)
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(grid, "grid_lyr")

            # Select lines inside gridDivision and add them to the previous selection
            print "Selecting "+lineFC+" inside GridDivision "+str(oid)+"..."
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("grid_lyr", matchOption, lineFC, "", "ADD_TO_SELECTION")
            print lineFC+ " selected: "+str(datetime.now() - startTime)

            # Make Spatial Join
            print "Making SpatialJoin between "+lineFC+"and grid inside GridDivision "+str(oid)+"..."
            arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(grid, lineFC, lineFC+"_SpatialJoin_"+str(oid[0]), "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "", "", matchOption)
            print "Spatial Join of grid division "+ str(oid) +"and "+lineFC+" done: "+str(datetime.now() - startTime)+"\n"


    # Select pieces of Spatial Join
    fileList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(lineFC+"_SpatialJoin*")

    # Search the name of the month in lines string
    month = re.search('scope_ais_(.+?)_Lines_Project', lineFC).group(1)
    #print month

    # Merge them
    print "Merging the spatial joins of "+month+"..."
    arcpy.Merge_management(fileList, month+"_Merged")
    print month+" merged: "+str(datetime.now() - startTime)+"\n"

    #Delete spatial join feature classes to save space in disk
    for deleteSpatialJoinFC in fileList:
        arcpy.Delete_management(deleteSpatialJoinFC)
    print "Deleted Spatial Joins to save space in disk"

    # Dissolve it
    print "Dissolving "+month+"..."
    arcpy.Dissolve_management(month+"_Merged", month+"_Dissolve", "TARGET_FID", [["Join_Count", "SUM"]])
    print "Dissolved: "+str(datetime.now() - startTime)+"\n"

    #Delete merged feature classes to save space in disk
    arcpy.Delete_management(month+"_Merged")
    print "Deleted merged feature class to save space in disk"+"\n"

    # Make raster
    print "Making "+month+" raster..."
    arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(month+"_Dissolve","SUM_Join_Count", month+"_2014_Raster")
    print "RASTER "+month+" READY!!: "+str(datetime.now() - startTime)+"\n"

#Print end time
print "Finished "+str(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

This printed messages might also help understand the problem. You can see that after the message:

> RASTER april READY!!: 0:00:24.593000

the new file *scope_ais_august_Lines_Project* starts but the OID is 7 and not 0

```
THIS IS THE LINE FILE: scope_ais_april_Lines_Project
1
GridDivision number 1 selected: 0:00:01.656000
Grid selected: 0:00:01.687000
Selecting scope_ais_april_Lines_Project inside GridDivision (1,)...
scope_ais_april_Lines_Project selected: 0:00:01.843000
Making SpatialJoin between scope_ais_april_Lines_Projectand grid inside GridDivision (1,)...
Spatial Join of grid division (1,)and scope_ais_april_Lines_Project done: 0:00:05.265000

2
GridDivision number 2 selected: 0:00:05.297000
Grid selected: 0:00:05.312000
Selecting scope_ais_april_Lines_Project inside GridDivision (2,)...
scope_ais_april_Lines_Project selected: 0:00:05.469000
Making SpatialJoin between scope_ais_april_Lines_Projectand grid inside GridDivision (2,)...
Spatial Join of grid division (2,)and scope_ais_april_Lines_Project done: 0:00:08.891000

5
GridDivision number 5 selected: 0:00:08.922000
Grid selected: 0:00:08.937000
Selecting scope_ais_april_Lines_Project inside GridDivision (5,)...
scope_ais_april_Lines_Project selected: 0:00:09.094000
Making SpatialJoin between scope_ais_april_Lines_Projectand grid inside GridDivision (5,)...
Spatial Join of grid division (5,)and scope_ais_april_Lines_Project done: 0:00:12.511000

6
GridDivision number 6 selected: 0:00:12.527000
Grid selected: 0:00:12.558000
Selecting scope_ais_april_Lines_Project inside GridDivision (6,)...
scope_ais_april_Lines_Project selected: 0:00:12.714000
Making SpatialJoin between scope_ais_april_Lines_Projectand grid inside GridDivision (6,)...
Spatial Join of grid division (6,)and scope_ais_april_Lines_Project done: 0:00:16.136000

7
GridDivision number 7 selected: 0:00:16.168000
Grid selected: 0:00:16.183000
Selecting scope_ais_april_Lines_Project inside GridDivision (7,)...
scope_ais_april_Lines_Project selected: 0:00:16.355000
Making SpatialJoin between scope_ais_april_Lines_Projectand grid inside GridDivision (7,)...
Spatial Join of grid division (7,)and scope_ais_april_Lines_Project done: 0:00:19.777000

Merging the spatial joins of april...
april merged: 0:00:21.365000

Deleted Spatial Joins to save space in disk
Dissolving april...
Dissolved: 0:00:23.249000

Deleted merged feature class to save space in disk

Making april raster...
RASTER april READY!!: 0:00:24.593000

THIS IS THE OID  7
THIS IS THE LINE FILE: scope_ais_august_Lines_Project
7
GridDivision number 7 selected: 0:00:24.624000
Grid selected: 0:00:24.640000
Selecting scope_ais_august_Lines_Project inside GridDivision (7,)...
scope_ais_august_Lines_Project selected: 0:00:24.796000
Making SpatialJoin between scope_ais_august_Lines_Projectand grid inside GridDivision (7,)...
Spatial Join of grid division (7,)and scope_ais_august_Lines_Project done: 0:00:28.259000

Merging the spatial joins of august...
august merged: 0:00:28.884000

Deleted Spatial Joins to save space in disk
Dissolving august...
Dissolved: 0:00:29.633000

Deleted merged feature class to save space in disk

Making august raster...
RASTER august READY!!: 0:00:30.930000

THIS IS THE OID  7
Finished 0:00:30.930000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you create a selection on your `gridDivision` layer. The cursor then only iterates through selected features.

Clear your selection after your cursor.

```
# Go through all lines feature classes
for lineFC in linesList:
    print "THIS IS THE LINE FILE: "+lineFC
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(gridDivision, ["OID@"]) as cursor:
        for oid in cursor:
            print (oid[0])
            #print "THIS IS THE OID  " +str(oid[0])
            ...other code...

    # Clear selection <--------- NEW CODE
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(gridDivision, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
```